# Subscribe user to list

Tags: 7, rules

I have a forum site and I **need sign up user list** (on profile page). So every user should sign up for new forum posts. Basically, I need a user group which I can attach in rules and send them email with new thread details.

**Is there a module for this or do I need create a custom module?** If I need my own module is this a good solution - Create content type "user_list" and attach users to nodes via user reference field. Then in Rules settings I will attach this user_list and send email to all users(via user refernce) in this node. Or is there a better alternative?

Thank you for response

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to use Organic Groups and Notifications ?
There is also *Organic groups e-mail blast* module I didn't try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be light-weight your should consider using https://drupal.org/project/userqueue

You can add users to a queue (similar to the nodequeue) and then use this user-queue along with views, and [VBO](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)

I am not sure if it has integration with Rules. If it has, it should make your work much easier.